Inspect Element/chrome devtools unfolding properties problem
When i go to inspect element and to console, and type the command:"console" in. the message: "console" comes in. I can see the message: console´s proparties and unfold them, though thats needs to be done manually, is there a way or command to unfold all properties of the message console all at once?
All my own attempts have failed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
